# Creating Matrix using Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

i was given an assignment to do, writing a class array and class Matrix, the matrix class is going to use array class to create its matrix, it is like an array pointing on other arrays, my problem is everything went fine but when i tried to do the addition of of two matrix that i created i keep having NullPointerException, this is my entire code. i have pointed on my error in the code below thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Matrix {
    public Vector mat[];
    public static int m;
    static int i, j;
    Scanner sc;

    Matrix() {
        m = 0;
        mat = null;
    }

    Matrice(int m, int n) {
        Matrix.m = m;
        Vector.n = n;
        mat = new Vector[100];
        // mat[i]=new Vector(100);
    }

    public void fillmatrix() {
        mat = new Vector[100];
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter the number of the rows");
        Matrix.m = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("enter the number of your columns");
        Vector.n = sc.nextInt();
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            mat[j] = new Vector(Vector.n);
            mat[j].fillmatrix();
        }
    }

    public void DisplayMatrix() {
        System.out.println("Th matrix you have entered: ");
        for (i = 0; i < Vector.n; i++) {
            mat[i].Display();
        }

        public static Matrix Addition(Matrix mat1, Matrix mat2) {
            Matrix mat3 = new Matrix();
            for (j = 0; j < Vector.n; j++) {
                for (i = 0; i < Matrix.m; i++) {
                    mat3.mat[i].t[j] = (mat1.mat[i].t[j]) + (mat2.mat[i].t[j]); < -- -- -- -- - where the mistake but i can 't solve it ://>
                }

            }
            return mat3;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Matrix Mat1 = new Matrix();
        Matrix Mat2 = new Matrix();
        Matrix Mat3 = new Matrix();
        Mat1.fill();
        Mat1.affiche2();
        Mat2.fill();
        Mat2.affiche2();
        Mat3 = Matrix.Addition(Mat1, Mat2);
        Mat3.affiche2();
    }

    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Vector {
        public static int n;
        static int i;
        static int j, k;
        int t[];
        static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        Vector(int n) {
            Vector.n = n;
            t = new int[100];
        }

        Vector() {
            Vector.n = 0;
            t = null;
        }

        public void fill() {
            t = new int[100];
            sc = new Scanner(System.in);

            for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                System.out.println("enter " + i + "° element of your array");
                t[i] = sc.nextInt();
            }
        }

        public void contain(Vector Tab) {
            i = 0;
            j = 0;
            if (n <= Tab.t.length) {
                while (j < Tab.t.length) {
                    if (t[i] != Tab.t[j]) {
                        j++;
                        i = 0;
                    } else {
                        i++;
                        j++;
                    }
                }
                if (i > n) {
                    System.out.println("the array 1 is contained in array 2");
                }
                els
                System.out.println("the array 1is not contained in array2");
            }
        } else {
            while (i < n) {
                if (t[i] != Tab.t[j]) {
                    i++;
                    j = 0;
                } else {
                    i++;
                    j++;
                }
            }
            if (j > n) {
                System.out.println("the array 2 is contained in array 1");
            } else {
                System.out.println("the array 2 is contained in array 1");
            }
        }
    }

    boolean appartient(int x) {
        i = 0;
        boolean found = false;
        while ((i < n) && (t[i] != x)) {
            i++;
        }
        if (i >= n)
            System.out.println("le x n'appartient pas a votre Tableau");
        else {
            System.out.println("le x appartient a votre tableau");
            found = true;
        }
        return found;
    }

    public void Display() {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println(t[i]);
        }
    }

    public void Order() {
        int j, tmp;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
                if (t[i] > t[j]) {
                    tmp = t[i];
                    t[i] = t[j];
                    t[j] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println("your array ordered  " + t[i]);
        }
    }

    void inser(int x) {
        if (appartient(x) == true) {
            System.out.println("Insersion is impossible, the value already exist");
        } else {
            for (i = n;
                (i > 0) && (t[i - 1] > x); i--)
                t[i] = t[i - 1];

            t[i] = x;
            n++;
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                System.out.println(t[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void fusionner(Vector tab1, Vector tab2) {
        Vector FUS = new Vector(tab1.t.length + tab2.t.length);
        i = 0;
        j = 0;
        k = 0;
        while ((i < tab1.t.length) && (j < tab2.t.length))
            if (tab1.t[i] < tab2.t[j]) {
                FUS.t[k] = tab1.t[i];
                k++;
                i++;
            } else {
                FUS.t[k] = tab2.t[j];
                k++;
                j++;
            }

        while (i < n) {
            FUS.t[k] = tab1.t[i];
            k++;
            i++;
        }
        while (j < n) {
            FUS.t[k] = tab2.t[j];
            k++;
            j++;
        }

        System.out.println("your arrays after the fusion is ");
        for (k = 0; k < tab1.t.length + tab2.t.length; k++)
            System.out.println(FUS.t[k]);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Vector tab1 = new Vector();
        System.out.println("Enter n");
        n = sc.nextInt();
        tab1.fill();
        tab1.Display();
        tab1.trier();
        Vector tab2 = new Vector();
        tab2.fill();
        tab2.affiche();
        tab2.trier();
        fusionner(tab1, tab2);
        tab1.contain(tab2);
        tab2.appartient(5);
        tab1.inser(6);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to put this as an answer instead of a comment since it was looking quite cluttered.

When you write `Matrix mat3 = new Matrix();`, you are invoking the constructor `Matrix()`, which you will find, sets `mat = null;`. So, as soon as you write something `mat3.mat[i].**something**`, you are looking for `[null].**something**`, which doesn't make a lot of sense.

I speculate that a call to `fillmatrix()` after initializing `mat3` is probably something you might be looking for.

Hope that I have been able to show you where you are going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your advise , i have made some changes on my code based on your advices, and keep doing addition of two matrix and the result is in a third matrix like this :mat3.mat[i].t[j]=(mat1.mat[i].t[j])+(mat2.mat[i].t[j]); i still have  Nullpointer problem, any advice , thanks.

Comment: @HananeEvancho `Matrix Addition` is not a valid function name (space); this function is written **inside** `DisplayMatrix`; Java does not allow nesting functions like this.

Comment: @HananeEvancho It would be nice, if you could accept/upvote an answer if your issue is resolved. From [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), "Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved."

Answer (score 0):

Vecteur class..

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Vecteur {
    public int n;
    static int i;
    static int j, k;
    int t[];
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Vecteur(int n) {
        this.n = n;
        t = new int[n];
    }
    Vecteur() {
        this.n = 0;
        t = null;
    }
    public void remplir() {
        this.t = new int[100]
            /*System.out.println("donner le nombre d'element a lire");
    n=sc.nextInt();*/
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println("donner le " + i + "° element a lire");

            t[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
    }
    public void contenu(Vecteur Tab) {
        i = 0;
        j = 0;
        if (n <= Tab.n) {
            while (j < Tab.n)

            {
                if (t[i] != Tab.t[j]) {
                    j++;
                    i = 0;
                } else {
                    i++;
                    j++;
                }

            }
            if (i > n) {
                System.out.println("Le tableau 1 est contenu dans tableau 2");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Le tableau 1 n'est pas contenu dans tableau 2");
            }
        } else {
            while (i < n)

            {
                if (t[i] != Tab.t[j]) {
                    i++;
                    j = 0;
                } else {
                    i++;
                    j++;
                }

            }
            if (j > n) {
                System.out.println("Le tableau 2 est contenu dans tableau 1");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Le tableau 2 n'est pas contenu dans tableau 1");
            }

        }
    }
    boolean appartient(int x) {
        i = 0;
        boolean trouve = false;
        while ((i < n) && (t[i] != x)) {
            i++;
        }
        if (i >= n)
            System.out.println("le x n'appartient pas a votre Tableau");
        else {
            System.out.println("le x appartient a votre tableau");
            trouve = true;
        }
        return trouve;
    }
    public void affiche() {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println(t[i]);
        }

    }
    public void trier() {
        int j, tmp;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
                if (t[i] > t[j]) {
                    tmp = t[i];
                    t[i] = t[j];
                    t[j] = tmp;

                }

            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            System.out.println("Les élements de tableau aprés le trie sont  " + t[i]);

        }
    }

    void insere(int x) {
        if (appartient(x) == true) {
            System.out.println("L'insersion est impossible, La valeur existe deja!");

        } else {

            for (i = n;
                (i > 0) && (t[i - 1] > x); i--)
                t[i] = t[i - 1];
            /* VAL est copié à la position du dernier */
            /* élément déplacé. */
            t[i] = x;

            n++;


            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                System.out.println(t[i]);

        }
    }

    static void fusionner(Vecteur tab1, Vecteur tab2) {

        Vecteur FUS = new Vecteur(tab1.n + tab2.n);

        i = 0;
        j = 0;
        k = 0;
        while ((i < tab1.n) && (j < tab2.n))
            if (tab1.t[i] < tab2.t[j]) {
                FUS.t[k] = tab1.t[i];
                k++;
                i++;
            } else {
                FUS.t[k] = tab2.t[j];
                k++;
                j++;
            }

        while (i < tab1.n) {
            FUS.t[k] = tab1.t[i];
            k++;
            i++;
        }
        while (j < tab2.n) {
            FUS.t[k] = tab2.t[j];
            k++;
            j++;
        }

        /* Edition du résultat */
        System.out.println("Le tableau aprés le fusion est ");
        for (k = 0; k < tab1.n + tab2.n; k++)
            System.out.println(FUS.t[k]);

    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        System.out.println("donner le nombre d'element de la table 1");

        Vecteur tab1 = new Vecteur(100);

        tab1.n = sc.nextInt();

        tab1.remplir();
        tab1.affiche();
        tab1.trier();

        System.out.println("donner le nombre d'element de la table 2");

        Vecteur tab2 = new Vecteur(100);
        tab2.n = sc.nextInt();

        tab2.remplir();
        tab2.affiche();
        tab2.trier();

        fusionner(tab1, tab2);

        tab1.contenu(tab2);
        tab2.appartient(5);
        tab1.insere(6);
    }
}
```

Matrix class..

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Matrice {

    public Vecteur mat[];
    public int m, n;
    static int i, j;
    Matrice() {
        m = 0;
        mat = null;

    }
    Matrice(int m, int n) {
        this.m = m;
        this.n = n;

        mat = new Vecteur[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            mat[i] = new Vecteur(m);
        }
    }
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void remplir() {
        mat = new Vecteur[m];

        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            mat[j] = new Vecteur(this.n);
            mat[j].remplir();
        }
        public void affiche2() {
            System.out.println("L'affichage de votre matrice");

            for (j = 0; j < this.m; j++) {
                System.out.println("La ligne" + j);

                mat[j].affiche();

            }
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            Matrice Mat1 = new Matrice(100, 100);

            System.out.println("donner le nombre de votre Ligne a lire de la      matrice1");
            Mat1.m = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("donner le nombre de votre Colomne a lire de la matrice1");
            Mat1.n = sc.nextInt();
            Mat1.remplir();
            Mat1.affiche2();

            Matrice Mat2 = new Matrice(100, 100);
            System.out.println("donner le nombre de votre Ligne a lire de la matrice2");
            Mat2.m = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("donner le nombre de votre Colomme a lire de la matrice2");
            Mat2.n = sc.nextInt();

            Matrice Mat3 = new Matrice(100, 100);

            Mat2.remplir();
            Mat2.affiche2();

            Mat3 = Matrice.somme(Mat1, Mat2);
            Mat3.affiche2();
        }
        public static Matrice somme(Matrice mat1, Matrice mat2) {
            Matrice mat3 = new Matrice(mat1.m, mat1.n);

            for (int j = 0; j < mat1.n; j++) {
                for (int i = 0; i < mat1.m; i++) {
                    mat3.mat[i].t[j] = (mat1.mat[i].t[j]) + (mat2.mat[i].t[j]);
                }

            }

            return mat3;
        }

    }
}
```